# how to remove windows if already combined with ubuntu

Tags: hard-drive, uninstall, system

I installed ubuntu next to windows how would I go about getting windows removed without deleting my ubuntu?

Comment: Try [OS-Uninstaller](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller).

Answer (score 0):

**First things first, back up any important data. You will be modifying partitions, which can cause loss of data if done incorrectly.**

If you don't need anything off of Windows first, just delete the Windows partition and resize your Ubuntu partition to fill the available space.

1. Boot from your Ubuntu live CD
2. At the terminal, run:

> $ gksudo gparted&

3. Select the Windows partition (It will be formatted NTFS)
4. Delete the Windows partition
5. Select the Ubuntu partition, select resize, and set it to take all unallocated space
6. Reboot normally and enjoy

Windows will still appear in the GRUB menu, so to remove it from GRUB, run:

> $ gksudo gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg

Look for this following section:

```
 ### END DEBIAN AUTOMAGIC KERNELS LIST

 # This is a divider, added to separate the menu items below from the Debian
 # ones.
 title           Other operating systems:
 root


 #This entry automatically added by the Debian installer for a non-linux OS
 # on /dev/sda1
 title           Microsoft Windows XP Professional
 root            (hd0,0)
 savedefault
 makeactive
 chainloader     +1
```

And comment out the bottom section using #

Save & exit.

Reboot, then run:

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo reboot
```